# O que há de errado no código abaixo?

Tags: objective-c

Quando cliquei em "Run" no Xcode para rodar o código e ver se está tudo certo, disse que deu tudo certo ("Build Succeeded"), mas na saída do código aparece o seguinte:

> 2015-12-11 17:35:38.289 prog1[36561:1080062] The value of myfraction
>   is: (lldb)

Não deveria aparecer isso? :

> 2015-12-11 17:35:38.289 prog1[36561:1080062] The value of myfraction
>   is:   1/3.

Segue o código.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Fraction : NSObject

-(void) print;  
-(void) setnumerator: (int) n;  
-(void) setdenominatior: (int) d;  

@end  

@implementation Fraction  
{  
    int numerator;  
    int denominatior;  
}  
-(void) print  
{  
    NSLog(@"%i/%i", numerator, denominatior);  
}  
-(void) setnumerator:(int) n  
{  
    numerator = n;  
}  
-(void) setdenominatior:(int) d  
{  
    denominatior = d;  
}  
@end


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])  
{
    @autoreleasepool {  
        Fraction *myFraction;  

        myFraction = [Fraction alloc];  
        myFraction = [myFraction init];  

        [myFraction setnumerator: 1];  
        [myFraction setdenominatior: 3];  

        NSLog(@"The value of myfraction is:");  
        [myFraction print];  

    }  
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: O código está correto. Por um acaso você não marcou aquela linha para debug? Provável que seja isso...

Answer (score 2):

Para imprimir um inteiro você deve usar %d, e não %i, assim como em C. Nesse caso seu print deveria ser assim:

```
NSLog(@"%d/%d", numerator, denominatior);
```